# Jenkins does not load plugins on EC2, https

Tags: https, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I've just installed Jenkins on an EC2 machine. Jenkins is served via Apache with SSL on port 443. I haven't bought a certificate yet, so the https connection is insecure.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my_host_name
    ServerAlias ci

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost off
    ProxyPass    / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Jenkins refused to update my plugins. I've checked the URL at `Manage Jenkins` → `Manage Plugins` → `advanced`, and it was http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json. I've tried downloading the file from `curl` at the server and it was downloaded without problems.

Why can't Jenkins download the json file for the updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by using the secure coutnerpart for the url

```
https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
```

Instead of:

```
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
```

Comment: This is misleading, the urls are identical